# Create OpenVPN connection on iOS

Tags: ios, openvpn

I want to create OpenVPN connection in my application, can't find any information if it is possible without OpenVPN connection app installed.
Is it possible to establish OpenVPN connection programatically using Network Extension without OpenVPN app installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create [OpenVPN Connect](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/openvpn-connect/id590379981?mt=8) in iOS device without OpenVPN connection app installed.

As you can see all VPN providers like [PureVPN](https://support.purevpn.com/openvpn-guide-for-ipad-iphone) and [privateinternetaccess](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ios-openvpn-connect) and many others create OpenVPN connection via OpenVPN app only.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

To check if openVPN is installed or not you can use following code which I found from [OpenVPN doc](https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-ios-faq.html)

```
BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"openvpn://"]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I check programatically if OpenVPN vpn is connected? can I connect it programatically if it is not?

Comment: @Saik0s I have updated the answer with how check if OpenVPN app is installed. If it is not installed I think you can redirect to appstore link of OpenVPN

Comment: thanks, but I mean if device connected to OpenVPN vpn, can I check it somehow programatically? And can I programatically reconnect to it if not connected?

Comment: Yes it possible without OpenVPN app
https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-ios-faq.html
By installing configured mobileconfig file into device.